# VSURF and randomForest

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to use VSURF and randomForest in R, but the functions in the libraries like predict.VSURF, predict.randomForest and plot.VSURF are not working and I'm getting the following error:

Error: could not find function "predict.VSURF"

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(randomForest)
library(VSURF)
data(cars)
fit <- VSURF(x = cars[1:402,2:ncol(cars)], y = cars[1:402,1])
#At this step I get the error: Error: could not find function "predict.VSURF"
preds <- predict.VSURF(fit, newdata = cars[403:804,2:ncol(cars)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R will recognize `fit` as a VSURF class object and call `VSURF.predict` for it. You just use `predict()` instead.

Also, in looking at your example, VSURF seems to fail for only one x variable throwing this error:

> Error in matrix(NA, nrow = nfor.thres, ncol = ncol(x)) : 
>     non-numeric matrix extent

Using `mtcars` and only `predict()`, VSURF works fine for me.

```
data("mtcars")
fit <- VSURF(x = mtcars[1:25,2:ncol(mtcars)], y = mtcars[1:25,1])
preds <- predict(fit, newdata = mtcars[26:32, 2:ncol(mtcars)])
```

Comment: Do you know why preds has two columns?  I think that the "pred" column is the predictions, but I'm unsure what the other column is for

Comment: @IJH VSURF seems to iteratively predict the data, once in an 'interpretation' step and finally in a 'prediction' step. You can limit the output by using `step = "pred"`.